# Java Narrowing Reference Conversion from a type to an interface

Tags: java, casting, type-narrowing

Trying to understand java narrowing conversion from a class to an interface. The JLS([JLS-5.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6)) states:

> From any class type C to any non-parameterized interface type K, provided that C is not final and does not implement K.

To test this, I created a class and an interface. Then tried casting the class to the interface, but get a run-time ClassCastException. This is a sample of my code.

```
class NarrowingReferenceConversion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        S s = new S();
        T t = (T)s;

    }
}

interface T
{
    public void print();
}

class S
{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("S.print()");
    }
}
```

On compiling and running the above I get the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: S cannot be cast to T

Comment: Your class S should implement interface T. In this case cast will succeed.

Comment: At the end of 5.1.6 there is :"Such conversions require a test at run time to find out whether the actual reference value is a legitimate value of the new type. If not, then a ClassCastException is thrown. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a conversion that is not guaranteed to work, just like casting a reference of a base class to a sub-class is not guaranteed to work. That's why it is considered a narrowing conversion.

The compiler knows that the conversion might work at runtime, so it allows it, but if it doesn't work, `ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime.

Only if you assign to `s` an instance of a sub-class of `S` that does implement the interface `T`, the conversion will work.

```
class NarrowingReferenceConversion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        S s = new S2();
        T t = (T) s; // this will work, since S2 implements T

    }
}

interface T
{
    public void print();
}

class S
{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("S.print()");
    }
}

class S2 extends S implements T
{
}
```

Let's explain the two conditions of this conversion:

1. "C is not final" - if it was `final`, there would be no sub-classes of `C`, so the compiler knows for sure this conversion can never work, and compilation fails.
2. "does not implement K" - if `C` implements `K`, this is no longer a narrowing conversion. It becomes a [Widening Reference Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5), guaranteed to succeed at runtime. In fact, there would be no need to use the cast operator. A simple assignment will do.

Answer (score 1):

The simple thing is:

```
 S s = new S();
 T t = (T)s;
```

Given the **current** code you are showing, the compiler *could* know that this cast doesn't make sense, and **must** fail at runtime.

But thing is: your case here is a pretty specific example. The common use case is less "clear". As shown by Eran, it is pretty simple to construct a similar example where the cast at runtime might work, or not, depending on very subtle differences.

So, the pragmatic answer is: the fact that a compiler *could* know that a program is invalid and will fail later on doesn't necessarily cause a compiler to fail.

In other words: when you design languages, and construct compilers there are always trade offs to make. As in: sometimes it is just not worth adding a very specific check at compile time. You rather accept that a more generic rule that might result in failures at runtime instead of compile time.